# Optimal alignment of satellite images taken separately over the same geographic surface

Tags: image, satellite, alignment

I am given two satellite images of a location which has been subject to a natural disaster, one before the disaster and one after.  I am given bounding boxes for the images.The images have been aligned so that objects at ground level will appear at the same location in both images. For example, here is a picture of a shopping center about to be hit by Hurricane Harvey:

[image]

Here are the same bounding boxes drawn on the aligned post-disaster image:

[image]

It is visually evident that the bounding boxes are not well aligned with the post image, **for objects which are not at ground level**.  Per comment from Ian Turton below, this is due to different lookdown angle used for each image.

Suppose the pre and post images are both 1024x1024x3 RGB images. These are represented as NumPy arrays A and B. I would like to find a  transformation T(B) which best corrects for lookdown angle so that the bounding box is better aligned on B.  For example so that np.linalg.norm(A-T(B)) is minimized.   Is there a Python package that will do this for me, and how is the transformation expressed?  Assume that allowable transformation operations include rotation, translation, shear, and in general any kind of stretching or shrinking of the "fabric" of B so that it most closely lays on top of A.

This [2016 paper by Wang et al](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5087512/) proposes a solution.  Prior to reading it, I imagined this kind of solution:

1. [Project the 2D points into 3D space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76134/how-do-i-reverse-project-2d-points-into-3d), for both pre and post
2. Infer the angle of attack and satellite height for both pre and post images
3. Do a [perspective transformation](https://pysource.com/2018/02/14/perspective-transformation-opencv-3-4-with-python-3-tutorial-13/) from post angle/height to pre angle/height
4. Project the transformed 3D post image back to 2D

NOTE: The images above come from the [xView 2 Challenge](http://xview2.org/)

Comment: To me it looks like the bounding box of both images aligns with the footprint of the building, the **roof** of the building *appears* to move due to the lookdown angle of the image.

Comment: I concur.  I didn't think lookdown angle would matter on a satellite!  That said, intuitively I still want to deform the image so that the rooftop outlines align.  Is there a standard method for that?  My go-to idea is to shift the images on X and Y axis and take the norm of the diff and find the shift that minimizes that norm.  That works pretty well but I was hoping to hear that there is a more industry standard solution.

Comment: The problem with a single transform for the entire image is that different buildings would need different amounts of shift, due to different building heights. One option for solving this is to go through each building polygon separately and calculate the transform which results in the lowest over all variance between the before and the after image. In the ideal world, that would result in your roofs matching up, since they are the dominant feature, assuming that you cropped closely enough, and perhaps added a vegetation mask, to remove trees etc.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen, if the angle of attack is correctly inferred for both pre and post images, and the height of the satellite can be guessed from the scale, then shouldn't a single transformation should work for all buildings?  I guess that's the work of the 2D to 3D transform.  I gave a link for that problem above.  I.e. with that information I should be able to compute the exact transformation that moves the camera virtually from the post position to the pre position and then takes a 2D "picture" of the 3D model of 3D-reconstructed post from the pre position.

Comment: From the satellite imagery metadata you can get the sensor elevation angle. As for whether the same transform can be used for all houses, regardless of height - the two buildings in your own illustration needs two different offsets. The one of the left needs a bigger shift, since it is significantly taller than the one on the left.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen I found this paper which seems to directly address the topic: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5087512/  An ideal 2D to 3D transformation would correctly estimate individual building heights, in which case it would suffice to take a picture of the 3D model from the off-nadirness and height of the pre image.  For my immediate practical purpose it seems the best solution is to shift the polygon mask over the post image in the neighborhood of the mask until the diff of pre and post under the mask is minimized.  That gets me aligned rooftops per building.

Comment: I wasn't aware before, but this particular problem seems to be big business: https://blog.kitware.com/3d-reconstruction-from-satellite-images/ and an active research topic: https://www.dni.gov/index.php/newsroom/press-releases/item/1844-iarpa-launches-core3d-program-to-build-accurate-3-d-models-from-satellite-imagery

Comment: It is pretty much the inverse of a stereo photogrammetry problem. Lots of good fun in those problems, areas of research, and programming challenges.